# Google voice actions - Trying to own my brand name which appears reserved

Tags: actions-on-google, invocation

I am trying to do a beta release of my voice action  but it will not  since it shows that my [brand name is reserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPL4l.png). I have verified my website but it continues to show me "____ is a reserved brand name. Verify ownership here". what are my next steps? How can i own my brand name?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the Action Console of where you verified your website? Maybe it's not complete?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [this support form](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) and choose the option **Invocation Name Assistance** with your brand name and project id.